# PostgreSQL Upgrade from 13 to 15 causing pgAdmin connection to fail

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

We currently have a database hosted in pg 13.1 (with PostGIS 3.1.1) and we are keen to move to pg 15.3 (with PostGIS 3.3.3) all running on Windows 10.

I installed pg15 without issue. The pgAdmin 4 utility (bundled with postgres 15) connects okay.

Then I used the pg_upgrade.exe utility to successfully migrate our db to the new pg15 server.

```
pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir "D:\PostgreSQL\13\data" --new-datadir "D:\PostgreSQL\15\data" --old-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" --new-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin" --username=super_user
```

Our apps and services seem happy with the new pg15 database.

However, using the pg_upgrade.exe utility to migrate our db has resulted in some sort of issue whereby pgAdmin (the version bundled with 15) will no longer access our server.

Starting the newer pgAdmin results a timeout error on the UI and the following errors in the pgAdmin log file

```
2023-09-12 15:04:03,159: WARNING    werkzeug:    WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-09-12 15:04:03,159: WARNING    werkzeug:    Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.
2023-09-12 15:04:12,182: ERROR    pgadmin:    Exception when checking for update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
File "http\client.py", line 1282, in request
File "http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
File "http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
File "http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
File "http\client.py", line 975, in send
File "http\client.py", line 1447, in connect
File "http\client.py", line 941, in connect
File "socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
File "socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
TimeoutError: timed out
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v7\web\pgadmin\browser\__init__.py", line 435, in check_browser_upgrade
response = urlopen(url, data, 5)
File "urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
File "urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
File "urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
File "urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
File "urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
File "urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2023-09-12 15:04:46,062: ERROR    pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#3) - 'PostgreSQL 15'.
Error: connection timeout expired
```

I have installed the latest pgAdmin4 (v7.6) but this gives the same error.

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL the authentication changed.

> There are several password-based authentication methods. These methods operate similarly but differ in how the users' passwords are stored on the server and how the password provided by a client is sent across the connection.

scram-sha-256

Have you try this?

More informationy you find here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-password.html